# How to center input of form in table? HTML

Tags: html, css, forms, html-table

I want to put inputs in  one row.

```html
<table border='1' cellpadding="25" style='border-collapse: collapse;border-color: silver;'> 
<tr style='font-weight: bold;'>
<td width='350' align='center'>
<h2>Register:</h2><br>
Login: <input type="text" name="login" maxlength="20" size="25" /><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password" size="25" maxlength="32" /><br>
Repeat password: <input type="password" name="password2" size="25" maxlength="32" /><br><br>
</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: And by "row", you mean column, I assume?

Comment: Don't use tables for layout there are much better options. At least, don't use a single cell table.

Comment: @Siguza Yes, in column,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are trying to get all this aligned in the center.For that we have to use the the *"tr"* tag defines a row in an HTML table and *"th"* tag which defines a header cell in an HTML table.Try the following code :

```
<html>
<body>
<h2 align="center">Register</h2>
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>Login</td>      
            <td><input type="text" name="login" align="middle"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="pass" align="middle"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Repeat Password</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="rpass" align="middle"/></td>
        </tr>   

    </table>
```

Also we use the align property for table and the new rows we create to get what you desire.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 3 options:

1. using `CSS` & `position:relative` and play with `left' of each`inputs`, **that's not valid at all.**
2. Add some more `HTML`, I mean put each inputs on separate `td`. **this is the best choice I think**, and even better that you put the `label / text' of each input` on another `td` as well.
3. Using `div` (for example) instead of `td` for having more control and using `CSS` as well.

I strongly recommend you that using option #2, hope this help.

Answer (score -1):

Do it like that:

```
<table border='1' cellpadding="25" style='border-collapse: collapse;border-color: silver;'> 
<tr style='font-weight: bold;'>
<td style="width: 300px; text-align: right;">
Login: 
</td>
<td style="width: 300px; text-align: left;">
<input type="text" name="login" maxlength="20" size="25" />
</td>
</tr>

<tr style='font-weight: bold;'>
<td style="width: 300px; text-align: right;">
Password:
</td>
<td style="width: 300px; text-align: left;">
<input type="password" name="password" size="25" maxlength="32" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```